# dplyr - sort one table by a COL from another table

Tags: sorting, dplyr

I have a table with cars

[image: Table of cars with with a car name column. Names could duplicate]

And another table with rankings for each car

[image: Table of rankings for each car name]

How do I:

- Count (and %) of cars in CAR table
- Sort by RANK table

Need output

[image: Table with number of cars and percent of cars for each car name]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  In order to attract an answer, you need to tag your question with the language & technologies you are using, rather than some general-purpose tag like [tag:sorting].  I added [tag:dplyr], but you should [edit] your question to add a language tag (probably [tag:r]) and any other framework-related tags such as one that indicates the type of table you are using.  See [ask] and [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Comment: A [mcve] showing the code you have so far and where you are stuck would be ideal, and maximize your chance of getting help here.

Answer (score 0):

next time please provide a reproducible example as mentioned in the comments.

Anyway, this might help:

```
library(tidyverse)

# example datasets
df1 <- tibble(car = c("Prius", "Tesla", "Prius", "BMW"),
              name = NA_character_)

df2 <- tibble(car = c("BMW", "Prius", "Tesla"),
              rank = 1:3)

# joining
left_join(df2, df1 %>% 
            count(car)) %>% 
  select(rank, car, count = n) %>% 
  mutate(pct = count / sum(count) * 100)


# A tibble: 3 × 4
   rank car   count   pct
  <int> <chr> <int> <dbl>
1     1 BMW       1    25
2     2 Prius     2    50
3     3 Tesla     1    25
```